# Writing MySQL Node.js models using node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, models

I'm trying to find some good practices for writing MySQL models using `node-mysql`.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var client = app.settings.client; // Client is set in Express settings

var table = 'users';

var User = function() {

}

// Create the user with data from Facebook
User.prototype.createFromFacebook = function (name, first_name, last_name, email, location, gender, facebookId, facebookToken, callback) {
  client.query(
    'INSERT INTO ' + table +
    ' SET name = ?, first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, location = ?,' +
    ' gender = ?, facebook_id = ?, facebook_token = ?',
    [ name, first_name, last_name, email, location, gender, facebookId, facebookToken ],
    function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
      if(err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(null, results);
      }
    }
  );
}

// Get user with just their email address
User.prototype.getByEmail = function (email, callback) {
  client.query(
    'SELECT * FROM ' + table +
    ' WHERE email = ?',
    [ email ],
    function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
      if(err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(null, results);
      }
    }
  );
}
module.exports = User;
```

Any critiques or improvements on this would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: why should not use object specifier for 1st method

Comment: like the way you seperate things withe module.exports. It was more than 2 years so today how you improve it? Please share with us im really interested cok i like anything that looks like an orm

Comment: For instance https://github.com/michalkow/node-mysql-model

Answer (score 2):

As a improvement, you can refactor your code

1. Datasourceobject for db connection

```
const db = require(__dirname + '/myDatabaseInstance.js');
```

2. Create UserSchema model user.js defines fields, data type, validation rules, etc.

user.schema.js

```
{
 "ID" : {
      "field" : "id",
       "type" : 'integer',
       "validation_rules" : "onlyInteger"     
  },
"name" : {
      "field" : "name",
      "type" : "string",
      "validation_rules": "usernameregex"   
 }
}
```

2. Create Controller.js where you can have findAll, findById, create, update, delete, search API methods.

```
 class _controller {
        constructor(object, model_schema) {
            this._object = object;
            this._model_schema = model_schema;
        }
        setId(_id) {
            this.id = _id;
        }

        validateRules(validation_rules) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let error = {};
                let validation = new Validator(this._object, validation_rules);
                if (validation.fails()) {
                    error.type = "validation";
                    error.errors = validation.errors.errors;
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });
        };

        create() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let response = {};
                let error = {};
                this.validation_rules= 
                UserSchema.getRules(this._model_schema).get_validation_rules;
                this
                    .validateRules(this.validation_rules )
                    .then(validation_result => {
                        db.insert(this.table, this._object)
                          .then(result => {
                                response.status = 201;
                                resolve(response);
                            });

                    })

            });
        }
})
```

3. Create user.js which extends to common controller.js using user schema

```
 class user extends _controller {
        constructor(object) {
            super(object, "user_schema");
            this.object = object;
        }
  }
```

You can add new functionalities  in user.js code.

Answer (score 0):

**Your way looks just fine.**

Make sure when you get an error your return:

```
if (err) {
return callback(err)
}
```

or just use the else like you're doing.

Just for the sake of critique, here is what I do:

```
var db = require(__dirname + '/myDatabaseInstance.js');

var create = function (vals, next) {
  db.query('Insert INTO users SET ?', vals, next);
};

var load = function (selector, next) {
 db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ?', selector, function (err, vals) {
   if(err) { 
     return next(err);
    }
    //at this point you could return a user object
    //next(new User(vals[0]));
     //or just return the array.
    next(null, vals);
 });
};
module.exports = create;
module.exports = load;
```

I call it this way

```
var User = require(__dirname + '/user.js');
User.load({'id' : 1}, function (err, vals) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(vals);
});
```

My personal preference is to not use instances for my models. I found it started to get messy when I had relations.

For example, say you have a blog with posts that are stored in a separate table related to the User. It is tempting to make the User object have an array of posts. Now if you change this posts array, you have to remember to save the changed User to the database. I kept forgetting, so I just stopped using instances.

Comment: "create" is a javascript Object property and you're overloading it :). I like the pattern anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create model name abc.js with following code:
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');
var MyAppModel = mysqlModel.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
    user: 'ghgh',
    password: 'gfhgfh',
    database: 'gfhgh',
});


movie = new MyAppModel({tableName: "users"});



Now use this as following :
var abc = require(__dirname+'/routes/abc')
movie.find('id','all', function(err, rows) {
//console.log(rows)
})
movie.query("SELECT * from users", function(err, rows) {   
});
var value  ={'name': "value3"};
movie.save(value);
```